# Facing trouble with global variable in JS

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

Following code is to track user location,

```
var curr_loc; //global varible
function displayLocation(loc) {
    currLat = loc.coords.latitude;
    currLon = loc.coords.longitude;
    curr_loc = currLat + "," + currLon;
    alert(curr_loc); //Displaying latitude and longitude values 
}

function foo() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
    alert(curr_loc); //undefined
}
foo();
```

How can I access location values in foo method.

Comment: **Ignore this response, I must be tired**: Your code is correct, but you're not actually calling `displayLocation` so `curr_loc` never gets defined?

Comment: You forgot to declare `currLat`, and `currLon`...

Comment: in `foo` function I've called `displayLocation` function

Comment: @h2ooooooo: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);`

Comment: @amnotiam and yashwant - you're of course completely correct - I must be tired. Disregard my response. :)

Comment: try moving the alert to displayLocation. as @amnotiam said, its an asynchronous call.

Comment: oh sorry i also didn't see the function invoke line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation)` returns *before* the position is established, and `displayLocation` would be called at some point in the future when the position is available. `curr_loc` is undefined for some time after `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` returns, because `displayLocation` has not been called yet.

Comment: And what is your problem? `displayLocation()` will be called after the position is available; do whatever you need to do with the position there, not in `foo()`

Comment: What want access latitude and longitude values in `foo()`

Comment: You cannot access those values in `foo()`, because they are not yet available at that point. You pass a function to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` exactly because it is not known when the position will be available, so that function gets called when it is available. You are trying to use the position _strictly_ before it is available, which is not possible.